# I am using Left join with other table . There are multiple rows with the same p_id on other table . I want the row with latest p_id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am using Left join( on A.a_id = B.p_id ) for joining tables A and B .There are multiple rows with same p_id on the other table.
I want the row with latest p_id .

The column joining table A with table B is a_id and p_id . I want to JOIN both the
table and group the records and only want table B record with max bid .
Can anyone help me with mysql query finding the desired result . I have posted the
desired result below .

Mysql query :

```
 Select * from A Left JOIN B ON A.a_id =B.p_id group by p_id 
 having max(b_id)
```

Table A

```
a_id  column1 
 1   Adam
 2   Voge
```

Table B

```
b_id  p_id   column2
 1   1    dash
 2   1    Hash
 3   2    kyu
```

Desired Result should look like this

```
a_id b_id   column1 column2
 1   2      Adam    Hash 
 2   3      Voge    kyu
```

Comment: Please edit the question and show your query so far.

Comment: @RohitGupta updated it

Answer (score 0):

@surya singh..

```
with joined_data as (
select 
a.a_id,a.column1,b.p_id,b.column2
from tablea a
inner join tableb b on a.a_id= b.b_id
),
find_recent_data as (
select 
a_id,column1,
column2,
row_number() over (partition by a_id order by p_id desc)  key_column
from joined_data)
select * from find_recent_data 
where key_column=1;
```

Comment: * JOIN  a_id=p_id . Also i do not understand what is find_recent_data

Comment: after join tablea and tableb , need to filter recent data from tableb. hence applying row number